How to UEFI boot Debian after transferring the contents of a smaller drive from a BIOS booting computer to the drive in the UEFI only computer?
I have Debian 12 installed to BIOS boot on SATA drive. The MBR type partitioning was determined by the defaults set in the Debian installer. I copied the exact contents of this drive to new larger drive, which will be used by a different newer computer that can only UEFI boot. The smaller drive has a 250 GB capacity with a 512 byte sector size and the larger drive has a 500 GB capacity with a 4096 byte sector size. The larger drive is currently installed in a computer which can only UEFI boot.
What are the steps needed to convert the larger drive to GPT and install a working UEFI booting Grub?
The old computer has 2048 MiB of RAM memory, and the new computer has 4096 MiB of RAM memory. Since the memory is larger, I would like to enlarge the swap space accordingly.
MBR Partition Table Entries



Partition
Device
Boot
StartingSector
EndingSector
Size inSectors
Size
Type
Id




First Primary
/dev/sda1
*
2048
479561485
479559438
228.7 GiB
Linux Filesystem
83


Second Primary
/dev/sda2

479561486
488424194
8862709
4327 MiB
Linux Swap
82



Disk /dev/sda size is 232.9 GiB, 250074470400 bytes, 488426700 sectors @ 512 bytes/sector

The steps are given below.

Convert the MBR partition table to GPT.
This step requires booting from external media, which will allow basic Linux commands to be executed. This can be either on a USB flash drive or DVD. This answer uses a DVD. Here, SystemRescue was randomly chosen. The file downloaded from SystemRescue was systemrescue-11.03-amd64.iso.
Enter the command below to list all block devices. From the output, determine which block device is the drive. In this answer, the block device is /dev/sda.
lsblk

Enter the command below to confirm the sector size is 4096 bytes.
blockdev -v --getss /dev/sda

The command below creates a new empty GUID partition table (GPT). The existing MBR partition table is erased.
parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt

The root partition (containing ext4 Debian volume) needs to be added to the GPT. According to the table given in the question, this partition started a sector 1024 on the old drive, which has a 512 byte sector size. The new drive has a 4096 byte sector size, which is exactly 8 times larger. This means the partition resides on the new drive at sector 256, which is exactly 1024 divided by 8. The command given below adds the root partition to the GPT, which contains the ext4 Debian volume.
parted -- /dev/sda unit s rescue 256 -1

At this point, no attempt will be made to add a swap partition. This will be done at later step in this answer. Enter the command below to mount the ext4 Debian volume in the root partition. This will allow access to the fstab file, so the line pertaining to the swap volume can be commented out.
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt                                  

Enter the command below to output the fstab file with lines numbers.

Note: This output is shown in the section below titled "Contents of the SystemRescue Console".

cat -n /mnt/etc/fstab

The output shows line 9 contains the entry for the swap partition. The command below comments out this line.
sed -i '9s/^/#/' /mnt/etc/fstab

Enter the command below to confirm the correct line was commented out.

Note: This output is shown in the section below titled "Contents of the SystemRescue Console".

cat /mnt/etc/fstab

Enter the commands below to unmount /dev/sda1 and power off the computer.
umount /mnt
shutdown -P now

After powering off, remove the external media.

UEFI boot Debian without Grub.
This step requires booting the rEFInd Boot Manager from external media. Information regarding rEFInd downloads can be found here.  There are also links to download a CD-R image file or a USB flash drive image file. This answer uses a CD made from the refind-cd-0.14.2.iso file.
The rEFInd Boot Manager can instruct the UEFI to boot Linux distributions without using Grub. The process is outlined below.

UEFI boots from the external rEFInd media.
The rEFInd Boot Manager then installs an Ext4 driver in the UEFI.
The rEFInd Boot Manager searches the Ext4 formatted Debian volume and finds the Debian boot files.
The rEFInd Boot Manager displays a menu with a Debian icon.
The Debian icon is manually selected or selected automatically after a short delay.
The rEFInd Boot Manager instructs the UEFI to boot Debian. In this case, the boot file is shown below.
boot\vmlinuz-6.1.0-25-amd64

Also, in this case, the boot options are shown below.
ro root=UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 initrd=boot\initrd.img-6.1.0-25-amd64



Below is the rEFInd menu displayed after booting to rEFind.


Open a Terminal application window.
Enter the command below to become the root user.
sudo -s


Use the GParted application create and resize partitions.
The GParted application will be used to do the following.

Add a new 8613 MiB Swap partition
Add a 300 MiB EFI System partition
Expand the ext4 Debian volume and containing root partition to include all immediately following free space.


Note: The Disks application included with the installer can be used in place of GParted application. The Disks application will not FAT32 format the EFI System partition. So, if this is desired, then the mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sda3 command can be used after quitting the Disks application.

Enter the command below to install the GParted application.
apt update
apt install gparted dosfstools mtools

Enter the following to open the GParted application.
gparted

Select the unallocated space immediately after the /dev/sda1 partition, as shown below.

Create a new 8613 MiB swap partition with 301 MiB free space following, as shown below.

Select the unallocated space immediately after "New Partition #1", as shown below.

Create a new 300 MiB fat32 partition, as shown below.

Select the /dev/sda1 partition, as shown below.

Resize the ext4 volume and containing partition so 0 MiB of free space follows, as shown below.

Select the green check mark to "Apply All Operations", as shown below.

Set the flags, as show below, for /dev/sda3. This will change the partition type to EFI System.

The result is shown below. Quit the GParted Application.


Mount the EFI System partition.
Enter the commands given below.
mkdir -p /boot/efi
mount /dev/sda3 /boot/efi


Update the fstab file.
Enter the command below to view the fstab file.
cat /etc/fstab

Below is an example. The root (/) and swap UUIDs are of the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, where each x is a hexadecimal digit. Below the root and swap UUIDs have be replaced with {root partition UUID} and {original swap UUID}, respectively.
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID={root partition UUID} /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID={original swap UUID} swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0

The swap UUID needs to be updated and the UUID for EFI volume needs to added. The command below outputs the new UUIDs. The EFI UUID is of the form XXXX-XXXX where each X is a hexadecimal digit.
blkid -s UUID /dev/sda2 /dev/sda3

Example output is shown below. The EFI and swap UUIDs have be replaced with {EFI UUID} and {new swap UUID}, respectively.
/dev/sda2: UUID="{EFI UUID}"
/dev/sda3: UUID="{new swap UUID}"

To make the changes to /etc/fstab, you can use nano, some other editor or enter the commands below. When entering the commands below, replace {original swap UUID}, {new swap UUID} and {EFI UUID} with the corresponding actual UUID.
sed 's/#UUID={original swap UUID}/UUID={new swap UUID}/' /etc/fstab >fstab
echo UUID={EFI UUID} /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1 >>fstab
mv fstab /etc/fstab

When finish, the command below can be used to view the new fstab file. Note: the {root partition UUID} should be unchanged.
cat /etc/fstab

Below is an example.
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID={root partition UUID} /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID={new swap UUID} swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID={EFI UUID} /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1


Install Grub
Grub is first installed for BIOS booting, then for UEFI booting.
apt reinstall grub-efi
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit


Boot to Debian.
Power off the computer. Remove the external media. Boot to Debian.



The New GUID Partition Table (GPT)
GUID Partition Table (GPT) Entries



#
Device
StartingSector
EndingSector
Size in Sectors
Size
Type
PartitionType GUID




1
/dev/sda1
256
119877119
119876864
457.3 GiB
Linux Filesystem
0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4


2
/dev/sda2
119877120
122082047
2204928
8613 MiB
Linux Swap
0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F


3
/dev/sda3
122082048
122158847
76800
300 MiB
EFI System
C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B



Disk /dev/sda size is 466.0 GiB, 500363689984 bytes, 122159104 sectors @ 4096 bytes/sector

Contents of the SystemRescue Console
[root@sysrescue ~]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0 854.7M  1 loop /run/archiso/sfs/airootfs
sda      8:0    0   466G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   466G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1   944M  0 rom  /run/archiso/bootmnt
[root@sysrescue ~]# blockdev -v --getss /dev/sda
get logical block (sector) size: 4096
[root@sysrescue ~]# parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

[root@sysrescue ~]# parted -- /dev/sda unit s rescue 256 -1
Information: A ext4 primary partition was found at 256s -> 59945184s.  Do you
want to add it to the partition table?
Yes/No/Cancel? y                                                          
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

[root@sysrescue ~]# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt                                  
[root@sysrescue ~]# cat -n /mnt/etc/fstab
     1  # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
     2  #
     3  # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
     4  # be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
     5  # disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
     6  #
     7  # <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
     8  UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
     9  UUID=8dc76951-2a26-4636-8f09-f5abfe0ea68c swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
[root@sysrescue ~]# sed -i '9s/^/#/' /mnt/etc/fstab 
[root@sysrescue ~]# cat /mnt/etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
#UUID=8dc76951-2a26-4636-8f09-f5abfe0ea68c swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
[root@sysrescue ~]# umount /mnt
[root@sysrescue ~]# shutdown -P now


Contents of the Debian Terminal Window
dma@debian:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for dma: 
root@debian:/home/dma# apt update
   .
   .
   .
Lines were omitted for brevity.
   .
   .
   .
root@debian:/home/dma# apt install gparted dosfstools mtools
   .
   .
   .
Lines were omitted for brevity.
   .
   .
   .
root@debian:/home/dma# gparted
GParted 1.3.1
configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
libparted 3.5
root@debian:/home/dma# mkdir -p /boot/efi
root@debian:/home/dma# mount /dev/sda3 /boot/efi
root@debian:/home/dma# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
#UUID=8dc76951-2a26-4636-8f09-f5abfe0ea68c swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
root@debian:/home/dma# blkid -s UUID /dev/sda2 /dev/sda3
/dev/sda2: UUID="5d429772-7834-43c2-99ac-759e3c19aaeb"
/dev/sda3: UUID="91C0-108A"
root@debian:/home/dma# sed 's/#UUID=8dc76951-2a26-4636-8f09-f5abfe0ea68c/UUID=5d429772-7834-43c2-99ac-759e3c19aaeb/' /etc/fstab >fstab
root@debian:/home/dma# echo UUID=91C0-108A /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1 >>fstab
root@debian:/home/dma# mv fstab /etc/fstab
root@debian:/home/dma# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=82e62c10-56ab-43e1-96f8-9d7d959acf66 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=5d429772-7834-43c2-99ac-759e3c19aaeb swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=91C0-108A /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
root@debian:/home/dma# apt reinstall grub-efi
   .
   .
   .
Lines were omitted for brevity.
   .
   .
   .
root@debian:/home/dma# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@debian:/home/dma# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-25-amd64
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
root@debian:/home/dma# exit
exit
dma@debian:~$ 


Debian Installer Default Swap Space Size
The table below shows the default sizes chosen for the swap space by the Debian installer. From small amounts of RAM memory, the swap space is a little more than twice the amount of RAM. For large amounts of RAM, the swap space is a little more than the actual amount of RAM.



RAM Memory
Swap Space




2048 MiB
4327 MiB ≃ 4.23 GiB


4096 MiB
8.41G ≃ 8613 MiB


8192 MiB
9011 MiB ≃ 8.8 GiB


12288 MiB
12.85 GiB ≃ 13157 MiB




Converting to GPT isn't strictly necessary, preferable but not mandatory for Linux, only for Windows.

@ChanganAuto: You are correct. Using a MBR partition table would be possible. To do this replace parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt in step 1 with parted /dev/sda mklabel msdos. The rest of the steps would remain unchanged.
